# Segue between ViewControllers without trigger control?

Tags: uitableview, ios5, storyboard

Is there a way in Storyboard UI to connect two UIViewControllers by a segue, without setting an object (Button, cell, ...), triggering the segue?
I want to fire the segue in code with **performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:** programmatically.

Why i want this is, i'd like to display a detail view controller, when a tableviewcell is selected, but only while the tableview is in editing mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just control-drag from one view controller to the other. And then of course don't forget to give the segue an identifier.